# Why might my users be being logged out after a minute or so?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I have a Asp Mvc 2 site using forms authentication.  When I run it locally I can log in and stay logged in indefinitely.

However when I put it on the server I seem to only stay logged in for a few minutes and then seems to be logged out.  I have looked at the cookies and there are 2 which seem relevant:

.ASPXAUTH which is a session cookie
.ASPXANONYMOUS which expires in 3 months.

When I refresh the page the cookies stay the same until I get logged out, when I seem to get a new .ASPXANONYMOUS cookie, but the .ASPXAUTH seems to be the same.

It seems that I might be able to stay logged in until I do something after a certain amount of time.  If I submit a form as soon as I am logged in then it works ok, but if I keep submitting data again and again then after a minute or so, one of the submits will happen as a logged out user and not as the user who was logged in, which all the other submits worked as.

What might cause this behaviour and how can I track down what is different & change it so that I can stay logged in indefinitely?

**EDIT**,

its a single server, but after some more investigation and searching the likely candidate seems to be that I am using more than 100mb on the server and the application pool is getting recycled.  I suppose now i need to know

- How can I check how much memory I'm using.
- What advice there is to reduce that.

Comment: what kind of server are you hosting on? what session provider are you using?

Comment: do you have only one server, or a farm of servers being load balanced?

Comment: @mcl, I'm not explicitly stating a session provider I don't think, so would be using the default, whatever that is?  Sorry I can't be more specific, but this is all a bit new to me.

Comment: @SamHolder: For the Q's in your edit: put these in their own Q (but check it won't be a duplicate first).

Comment: @Richard, thanks.  yeah I will if I need to, I wasn't expecting those to be answered here.  I'll try to have the sessions survive recycling as indicated in your answer.  thanks.

Comment: @SamHolder: for anything with any kind of significant interaction you'll need sessions to survive to handle machine restarts (e.g. security patching) as well as new software deployments even without app domain recycles within IIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could it be that the ASP.NET application is being re-cycled or shutdown (e.g. due to idle timeout, or newly built/changed assemblies)?

When an ASP.NET web application starts up it will, by default, generate encryption keys for view state and session cookies. This will invalidate any such data originally served from an earlier run of the application (or from a different system).

To have sessions survive ASP.NET application cycles (and multi-server farms) you can specify the keys in your `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <machineKey
    decryption="AES"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryptionKey="..."
    validationKey="..."
  />
```

where `decryptionKey` and `validationKey` are hex strings of length depending on the algorithm (with AES: 64 digits and SHA1: 128, for other algorithms check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w8h3skw9.aspx)).

These keys should be cryptographically generated, and .NET has the types to do this which can be used from PowerShell:

```
$rng = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider"
$bytes = [Array]::CreateInstance([byte], 16)
$rng.GetBytes($bytes)
$bytes | ForEach-Object -begin { $s = "" } -process { $s = $s + ("{0:X2}" -f $_) } -end { $s}
```

For AES use the above array length, for SHA1 use a length of 64.

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to have done the trick, at least I've not been logged out in the last few minutes, even when the pages took a while to load (which is presumably when the recycle was happening)

Comment: this will help the session keys survive, right? But if you put any actual data in Session you still need to make sure you're using a Session provider with non-volatile persistence, like SQL or files, right?

Comment: @mcl: Correct. In process session state dies with the process. Out of process is required, and that means SQL Server to survive a machine restart. I prefer to assume Session state is transient anyway, anything needed longer term needs to be in a persistent repository with Session as a cache.

Comment: There's also a great online/free tool that generates Machine keys: aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey In time: after adding the machine key I had to recreate the users and their passwords using ASP.NET Configuration present in Solution Explorer toolbar because passwords take into account the machinekey.

Comment: This is indeed the issue. See here for a good explanation of why this works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12206137/1026459

Comment: Your host might have feaure to generate these keys for you. Arvixe does! in MachineKey Generator

Answer (score 1):

It is quite likely that Session Timeout on the web server is configured to a much smaller timespan than you have set in your Form Authentication configuration in web.config.

The default Session Timeout is 20 minutes for IIS6 and IIS7.

If you have access to the web server's admin interface, you can raise the timeout via the GUI, but it can also be set from the config file if your IIS7 using the `<sessionState>` and `<sessionPageState>` sections:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check the webconfig authentication section

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="UniqueName" loginUrl="login.aspx" path="/"  >
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Ensure that the authentication cookie name for each hosted site is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Came here with a similar issue, following the suggestion by @Richard, I looked at the Application Pools' recycling settings. What I found was the settings were changed and the `Regular time intervals (in minutes)` value was set to 1 minute. This meant that the app pool was being recycled each minute.

To change that, Right-click on the application pool, select the `Recycling` option, change the value under `Regular time intervals (in minutes)`. I set it to the same value as the other Application Pools were using.

[image: Which setting to change]

This change fixed the issue, turns out it was set to a low value a while back while during some misguided troubleshooting with an expired SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If none of these work, check in the Application Pools and ensure that the Idle Timeout is set to 20+ minutes. Click on the application pool, select the `Advanced Settings` link to the right, find the `Process Model` section, and increase the `Idle Timeout` value there.